# MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection with JBOSS EAP 6.2.0

Tags: jboss, jms, ibm-mq, jboss6.x

I am trying to integrate JBOSS EAP6.2.0 with IBM MQ 7.5.
JBOSS servers are configured to run in a managed domain.

With JBoss 6.2, following steps are completed:
1. successfully deployed wmq.jmsra.rar file
2. Created resource adapter, connection factory and destination queue.

here is the snippet of the configuration:

```
<resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra">
<archive>
wmq.jmsra.rar
</archive>
<transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
<connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:jboss/jms/ivt/IVTCF" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="IVTCF">
<config-property name="port">
2414
</config-property>
<config-property name="hostName">
localhost
</config-property>
<config-property name="channel">
SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN
</config-property>
<config-property name="transportType">
CLIENT
</config-property>
<config-property name="queueManager">
MB7QMGR
</config-property>
<security>
<application/>
</security>
<validation>
<background-validation>false</background-validation>
</validation>
</connection-definition>
</connection-definitions>
<admin-objects>
<admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:jboss/jms/ivt/IVTQueue" enabled="true" use-java-context="false" pool-name="ivtQueue">
<config-property name="baseQueueName">
TESTQ
</config-property>
<config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">
MB7QMGR
</config-property>
</admin-object>
</admin-objects>
</resource-adapter>
```

With all configuration in place, I can see in the server logs that connection factory and destination is successfully bounded:
JBAS010401: Bound JCA AdminObject [java:jboss/jms/ivt/IVTQueue] JBAS010401: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:jboss/jms/ivt/IVTCF]

I am able to get this connection factory in my java code but when I am trying to create connection from the factory I am getting below error:
*

```
17:54:06,233 INFO [stdout] (http-/10.63.78.129:8010-1) Connection factory found !!
17:54:06,233 INFO [stdout] (http-/10.63.78.129:8010-1) Destination queue found !!
17:54:06,385 WARN [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.PoolByCri] (http-/10.63.78.129:8010-1) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011 An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.
at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:129)
at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:105)
at com.ibm.mq.connector.ConnectionBuilder.createConnection(ConnectionBuilder.java:197)
at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:434)
at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionImpl.<init>(ManagedConnectionImpl.java:138)
at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:190)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:781)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:344)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:397)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:365)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:329)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:302)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedJMSConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:194)
at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnectionInternal(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:153)
at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:138)
at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:123)
at com.tms.ice.apns.PutMessageToQueueUsingJNDI.putMessage(PutMessageToQueueUsingJNDI.java:31) [classes:]
at com.tms.ice.apns.GenerateAPNSRequest.doPost(GenerateAPNSRequest.java:137) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:91)
at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:72)
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem.
See the linked exception for further information.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:319) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.0 - p000-L120604]
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:233) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.0 - p000-L120604]
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:180) [com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.0 - p000-L120604]
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6254) [com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.0 - p000-L120604]
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createProviderXAConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:107) [com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.0 - p000-L120604]
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createXAConnectionInternal(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:378) [com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.0 - p000-L120604]
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(MQXAConnectionFactory.java:129) [com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.0 - p000-L120604]
at com.ibm.mq.connector.ConnectionBuilder.createConnection(ConnectionBuilder.java:172)
... 46 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195;AMQ9546: Error return code received. [1=java.lang.NoSuchMethodException[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.<init>(com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment, int)],3=Class.getConstructor0]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:822) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.0 - p000-L120604]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:666) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.0 - p000-L120604]
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:172) [com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.0 - p000-L120604]
... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.<init>(com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment, int)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2810) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1718) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:728) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.0 - p000-L120604]
... 53 more
17:54:06,401 INFO [stdout] (http-/10.63.78.129:8010-1) GenerateAPNSRequest.Result for posting message in the queue MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection.
```

*
I have searched multiple forums and were able to get to related topics but any solution if provided did not worked. No FDC were generated for mqrc 2195 mentioned in the stack trace and even replacing wmq.jmsra jar files from 7.0.1.13 to 7.5.0.0 did not worked.

Request you all to have a look and suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved an error like this by revising my code and make sure that every object is closed, also in all the catch structures.

The cause was that the MQ provider accepted a limited number of connections and at some point this pool got filled up. So you will have to close first all the connections to the queue and then rerun the corrected code.

Comment: Did you use JMS 2.x or 1.x .. By any chance did you use JMSContext ?